# How to get the Ascii value from Unicode string U+20B9 to get the indian rupee symbol?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsstringencoding

How to get the Ascii value from Unicode string U+20B9 to get the indian rupee symbol?we have tried to use Locale Identifier but it is giving Us Dollar.How to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has no ASCII code. Only the Unicode values U+0000 to U+007F have ASCII codes.

Some non-standard fonts assigned the Indian rupee sign to replace the ASCII grave accent (`) which is ASCII 60 (and Unicode U+0060). This is a stupidly incorrect assignment that won’t work with fonts other than the few that proudly and wrongly made the assignment.

From here: http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121011093254AAU72or

Answer (score 1):

ASCII does not include a code point for the Indian Rupee symbol.  You cannot get the ASCII value for it because it doesn't exist.  That's why they invented Unicode.

Comment: If you see the font list in the xcode,you will find out the rupee symbol.This is supported by apple from iO5 5.0 onwards.So We can use the rupee symbol as we can access $ symbol using code rather than keyboard